# Reading a number of lines from azure blob storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have csv files in azure which I read using the function with the following header :

```
get_blob_to_stream(container_name, blob_name, stream, snapshot=None,
        start_range=None, end_range=None, validate_content=False,
        progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, lease_id=None,
        if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None,
        if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
```

The `start_range` and `end_range` are good parameters if you want to bring a number of bytes from said blob, but say I know my blob is a csv and I precisely want it to bring me the lines from 1 to 1000, kind of like how I tell pandas `pd.read_csv(...,nrow=1000, skiprows = range(0,1))`. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Azure Documentation](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html?highlight=get_blob_to_stream), it doesn't look like that function will offer that functionality.

However, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091869/8433220), which seems promising. Maybe you can redirect the stream directly into pandas `read_csv` function and continue from there.