# Read data from Azure Blob to In-memory using python notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an container consisting of Blob, which consist of my data(csv file). I need to read this data into python notebook which I am using for Azure ML.

I had tried link [How best to convert from azure blob csv format to pandas dataframe while running notebook in azure ml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091830/how-best-to-convert-from-azure-blob-csv-format-to-pandas-dataframe-while-running)  but facing following issue.

Issue:
AzureSigningError: Incorrect padding

But my id and password is correct.

Request you to help.
Is there any another method to read files from Blob storage for Ml application in Azure notebook.

Regards,
sumit

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed & replaced w `azure-machine-learning`).

Comment: Have you seen this article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data You can mount your blob storage contains your data and download whatever files onto whatever compute/vm is hosting your notebook

Answer (score 0):

this is the documentation that comes with the AzureSigningError class which is part of the Python Azure Storage SDK.

```
Represents a fatal error when attempting to sign a request.
In general, the cause of this exception is user error. For example, the given account key is not valid.
Please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account for more info.
```

Most likely, your storage account name or storage account key are not correct.

When you provide a wrong combination on purpose, this would also be the exact error you get.

Hope this helps.

Tobias W.