# read csv from blob storage with Azure function no permissions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I would like to read csv file from Azure blob storage with python Azure function. Using the code below, I get  the error:

> [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/site/wwwroot/my_csv_file'

And the code snippet is:

```
work_directory= os.getcwd()
filename = my_csv_file
account_name = <blob_storage>
account_key = <blob_key>

os.chmod(work_directory, 0o777)

input_fpath=os.path.join(work_directory, filename)
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name=<input_container_name>, blob_name=filename,
                                          file_path=input_fpath)
```

How could I change permissions or how I can read csv to python in other way?

Comment: The error shows the error file is in your function disk not the blob file.

Comment: And in the python function it's default read-only that's why it shows Read-Only.

Comment: Any update on this issue, could you read file now?

Comment: @GeorgeChen I've solved this with block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(...).content

Comment: If you solve it, you could post you answer and mark it to close this question.

Comment: Sorry for the typo: block_blob_service.get_blob_to_*text(...)*.content should be insted of get_blob_to_path

Comment: I mean post it as an answer not update the question.

Comment: And are you sure you could use `chmod` method in the function ?

Comment: @GeorgeChen Thank you! I've posted my answer and corrected the code. No 'chmod' in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**
using `get_blob_to_text` instead of `get_blob_to_path`:

```
blobstring = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(<input_container_name>, file_name).content
```

The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091830/how-best-to-convert-from-azure-blob-csv-format-to-pandas-dataframe-while-running).

`chmod` is not required. So, the whole code is the following:

```
filename = my_csv_file
account_name = <blob_storage>
account_key = <blob_key>

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)
blobstring = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(<input_container_name>, filename).content
```

Answer (score 0):

For now the Python Azure function doesn't allow to write the file, it's read-only mode and this is not able to change. So you could neither use `chmod` method nor use `get_blob_to_path` cause you could write file to your disk.

So maybe you could read your file to a stream then send it to the response. You could refer to my code, I use the [Blob binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=python#input---example) to read a text file.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest,inputblob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

name = req.params.get('name')
if not name:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        name = req_body.get('name')

if name:
    return func.HttpResponse(inputblob.read(size=-1))
else:
    return func.HttpResponse(
         "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
         status_code=400
    )
```

[image]