# How to edit pdf from azure blob storage without downloading it locally? (using Fitz)

Tags: python, azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage, pymupdf

I have a pdf that is already in the blob storage. I need to highlight few lines in it and store it as a new pdf (again in blob storage). I tried finding it in the links below but couldn't. Below is the pseudo code:

```
import fitz


def edit_pdfs(path_to_pdf_from_blob)  

    ### READ pdf from blob storage
    doc = fitz.open(path_to_pdf_from_blob)

    ## EDIT doc (fitz.fitz.Document) - I already have working code to edit the doc , but won't put it here to avoid complexity


    ### WRITE pdf to blob storage
    doc.save(new_path_to_pdf_from_blob)
```

Answers already seen:

[Access data within the blob storage without downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790959/access-data-within-the-blob-storage-without-downloading)
[How can I read a text file from Azure blob storage directly without downloading it to a local file(using python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530300/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-azure-blob-storage-directly-without-downloading)
[Azure Blobstore: How can I read a file without having to download the whole thing first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733213/azure-blobstore-how-can-i-read-a-file-without-having-to-download-the-whole-thin)

Comment: You could read the blob data as stream instead of saving the file locally.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Do you mind sending across a link that can help me do this. I have been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467961/python-script-to-use-data-from-azure-storage-blob-by-stream-and-update-blob-by) , but the solution is not compatible with the latest version of azure storage as the method has been removed

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python#download-to-a-stream. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried in my environment and got the below results:***

Initially, I had one pdf document in my container with the name **`important.pdf`** with content like below.

[image]

You can use the below code to edit the pdf without downloading it locally.

**Code:**

```
from io import BytesIO
import fitz
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "your-connection-string"
blob_name = "important.pdf"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="test", blob=blob_name)

# Download the PDF file as bytes
pdf_bytes = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_bytes()
doc = fitz.open(stream=pdf_bytes, filetype="pdf")
page = doc[0]
rect = fitz.Rect(50, 50, 200, 200)
highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(rect)  
# Set the color of the highlight annotation
highlight.update()

new_blob_name = "demo.pdf"
modified_pdf_stream = BytesIO()
doc.save(modified_pdf_stream)
modified_pdf_bytes = modified_pdf_stream.getvalue() 

# Get a BlobClient object for the new PDF file
new_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="test", blob=new_blob_name)
new_blob_client.upload_blob(modified_pdf_bytes, overwrite=True)

#delete an original file
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="test", blob=blob_name)
blob_client.delete_blob()
```

**Output:**

[image]